# Need to run the backup command when errorlog having error like 3041 and 18210

Tags: sql-server

Hi Can you please help to run backup command automatically when error log have error like error 3041 and error 18210

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: actually what happened we are taking tape backups with third-party tools. we are facing some issues in that. we need to take local backup in server. I want to automate that when we get error 3041 or 18210 at that time automatically run the backup command in server. for this i need help to automate.

Comment: is there a chance to run the job automatically when we get the error  3041

Answer (score 0):

**Error 18210**

This message indicates that an I/O error was reported by the operating system after a file handle was successfully opened. The error occurs when reading from or writing to a device specified as part of a BACKUP or RESTORE command, often when there is not enough disk space available for a write operation. This error may also be seen if third-party software that uses a virtual device to perform SQL Server backups cancels the operation.

It looks like there is not enough disk space.

**Edit after new information about the needs**
To automate the backup on another way is that you can create a SQL Agent Job for it which does the backup to the other location.
Then, you can create an Alert for the given error which kicks of that job.

[image]

Alert for your error
[image]

In response tab you can add the job which will do the backup to the other location:
[image]

Comment: yes, we are taken tape backups when there is no enough disk space this error occurs at that time need to take local backup. is there any way to automate this

Comment: Well that wasn't very clear in the opening question ;-)
So you are running a backup, and when there is not enough space, it should create another backup to another location?

Comment: yes, but the job should be automatically

Comment: I've changed my answer. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your support I will try and come back to you. if it works.

Comment: Just a note that you should verify that this error number is written to the Windows eventlog. Agent polls the eventlog (not the errorlog file). There are cases when there are rare differences between what is in the eventlog vs the errorlog, so check eventlog just to be certain.

Comment: Good addition Tibor ;)

Comment: Hi Peter, when i try do the above process in response Tab. when create new I got below error. please find the below snap for reference

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Attempt to retrieve data for object failed for Server 'xxxxxxxxx'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)                                                                                        
         Additional Information:-                                                                                                                        
         Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: urn (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

Comment: Can you upgrade your SSMS to the latest version, or are you running on that?

Comment: ok i will upgrade SSMS. current version is 18